# How to create a simple DNN module?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I would like to know how to create a simple DNN module, for example a simple form like a Suscribe or similar.

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes my friend,,, Dot Net Nuke :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a really simple module [this](http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/DNN5_HelloWorld/Default.htm) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This post describes how you can do this: http://www.msquaredweb.com/blog/articles/MyFirstCSharpDotNetNukeModule.html

Answer (score 0):

Michael Washington has a number of tutorials and sample modules at http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/.

Answer (score 0):

you can start at the DNN website Free tutorial:
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Basic-Module-Development.aspx
Also have a look at Mitchel Sellers site
http://www.mitchelsellers.com/search-results.aspx?Search=develop+modules
and the above suggestions are great also